# how to add image in button with text?

Tags: javafx

```
enter code here

package buttonfx;

/**
*
* @author 1407305
*/
          import javafx.application.*;
          import javafx.event.*;
          import javafx.scene.*;
          import javafx.scene.control.*;
          import javafx.scene.image.Image;
          import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
          import javafx.scene.layout.*;
          import javafx.stage.*;
          public class Buttonfx extends Application {
          Label l=new Label("press the button");    // adding label
  public void start(Stage mystage) throws Exception  //starting   mystage                              
          {
          mystage.setTitle(("Button new gen"));
          FlowPane f=new FlowPane(); //creating flowpane
          //  Pane f=new Pane();
          Scene myscene=new Scene(f, 500,300);
          mystage.setScene(myscene);   //setting scene to stage
          ImageView imageDecline = new ImageView("C:\\Users\\kiit\\Documents\\icons\\colour.png");
          Button b=new Button("alpha" , imageDecline);
          Button b1=new Button("Beta" , imageDecline) ;
          b.setOnAction(MEHANDLER1);
          b1.setOnAction(MEHANDLER1);
          b.setLayoutX(200);
          b.setLayoutY(100);
          f.getChildren().addAll(l , b, b1);
          mystage.show();
          }
          EventHandler<ActionEvent> MEHANDLER1 = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
          {
          public void handle(ActionEvent ae)
          {   
          String str=((Button)ae.getTarget()).getText();
          if(str.equals("Alpha"))
          {
          l.setText( str + " was pressed");
          }
          if (str.equals("Beta"))
          {
          l.setText(str + " was pressed");
          }
          }
          };
          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          launch(args); 
          }
          }
```

In this code i am unable to insert image in button. in this m using two buttons which doing some small operation my only intension is to add image in both the button so please rectify this programe , and give me the correct way to do it.

Comment: Always post the complete stack trace in the question when your code throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the same node in two different places in the scene graph. Create one image (images are not nodes, they just encapsulate the image data), and create two image views from the image.

Additionally, the [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) and [`ImageView` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#ImageView-java.lang.String-) are expecting the **URL** of the image, not a path to a file.

```
File imageFile = new File("C:/Users/kiit/Documents/icons/colour.png");
Image imageDecline = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
Button b=new Button("alpha" , new ImageView(imageDecline));
Button b1=new Button("Beta" , new ImageView(imageDecline)) ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the code

```
b1.setGraphic(imageDecline);
b2.setGraphic(imageDecline);
```

and instantiate the buttons without the imageView.

Comment: no not happening it shows  Exception in application start  method.

Comment: Are you sure that your url is good on the ImageView? Sometimes it is easier to instantiate an Image and then put the Image in the ImageView's constructor.

Comment: yes buddy m sure i have checked it . its always throws an exception but why i don't know . So if there is any fault in other line then please rectify it . and thank you.

Comment: :- actually whats happening is when I insert ImageView in this program and when I run it it always show "Exception in Application start method" but when i exclude it then this program is working correctly. I have tried alot but dont know why it throws exception.

Comment: @Ravi but I provided an answer (see above) which explains why. Read the stack trace (all of it): it says something about duplicate nodes (i.e. you used the same node twice).

Comment: @James_D thank you so much  for ur help i got it and understand that concept. :-)